# Check if git branch contains commit with given subject

Tags: bash, git, grep

Given an exact subject line of a commit I want to know if a branch contains a commit with that subject.

What I have right now is: `git log --format="%s" -F --grep="$msg" "$branch" | grep -Fq --max-count=1 -- "$msg"`

I.e. search the log with a fixed-string grep and print the subject. Then search that subject with the same fixed-string and stop at the first match.

The 2nd grep is required because `git log --grep` may find the pattern anywhere in the commit message (e.g `Fixes "$msg"`)

However this has the downside that it seemingly always walks the **entire** history of that branch which takes quite long.

As a test I ran `git log --format="%s" -F --grep="$msg" "$branch" | grep -Fq --max-count=1 -- "$msg"` and `git log --format="%s" -F --grep="$msg" "$branch"` and they both took the same time although the commit to grep for is found/printed very fast (for the 2nd)

So is there a way to directly find a commit in a branch by a given subject (using fixed strings as `$msg` comes from another command and may contain regex-like characters) faster or at least make my log-grep-pipe exit faster (on success)?

Comment: Did you try removing the first `grep` and only using the second one to filter?
`git log --format="%s" "$branch" | grep -Fq --max-count=1 -- "$msg"`

Comment: I though a grep done by git might be faster. But seems it is not for the case where the commit is found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

`git log --format="%s" "$branch" | grep -Fqx --max-count=1 -- "$msg"`

Here `x` will match the entire line.. and max-count will return the first match.

Comment: I was already using `--max-count=1` but seems it indeed was the grep on the git history which made it slow. Match case now is almost instant vs 5.5s before. Non match case is 6.1s vs 5.4s before. So 10% slower in the worst case and extremely fast in the best case.